# Weak references cleared atomically with placement on reference queue?

Tags: java

Does the Java GC clear a weak reference atomically with placing the weak reference on the ReferenceQueue assigned to that reference? In other words, if a call to WeakReference.get() returns null, will the WeakReference be on the queue?

Comment: Why was this flagged as "unclear what you're asking"? Seems crystal clear to me.

Comment: Maybe the question could be elaborated more in depth. Currently only an expert understands it, therefore the *unclear*s I guess.

Comment: @Zabuza The question is already perfectly clear, and doesn't require any elaboration whatsoever. *Of course* if you don't know anything about the topic, the question will be incomprehensible. That doesn't make it 'unclear'. There is far too much of this sort of close-voting here. Don't encourage it, or excuse it.

Comment: @EJP That was not what I meant to say by that. I just think that this is the reason for it, of course that's not the way it is meant. If a question requires some expertise you should just skip it if you don't have it, not cast a close vote. However by elaborating it, giving some coding examples or whatsoever, you may be able to address more people, get them into the topic and so on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lets dissect [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ref/WeakReference.html) for WeakReference:

> Suppose that the garbage collector determines at a certain point in
>   time that an object is weakly reachable.
>
> At that time it will atomically clear all weak references to that
>   object and all weak references to any other weakly-reachable objects
>   from which that object is reachable through a chain of strong and soft
>   references.
>
> At the same time it will declare all of the formerly weakly-reachable
>   objects to be finalizable.
>
> **At the same time or at some later time it**
>   will enqueue those newly-cleared weak references that are registered
>   with reference queues.

It looks like the steps are:

1. Determine if object is weakly reachable.
2. Clear that object from its `WeakReference`. `WeakReference.get`
   will return `null`.
3. Mark that object finalizable.
4. Right after or at **some other time** do enqueue the
   `WeakReference` into the queue (if `WeakReference` was created with
   a queue).

*This means that even if `WeakReference.get()` returns `null` it is not guarantee that  `WeakReference.enqueue` will be `true` or `ReferenceQueue.poll` wont return `null`.*

See https://community.oracle.com/blogs/enicholas/2006/05/04/understanding-weak-references for more.

> **Reference queues**
>
> Once a WeakReference starts returning null, the object it pointed to
>   has become garbage and the WeakReference object is pretty much
>   useless. This generally means that some sort of cleanup is
>   required;WeakHashMap, for example, has to remove such defunct entries
>   to avoid holding onto an ever-increasing number of deadWeakReferences.
>
> The ReferenceQueue class makes it easy to keep track of dead
>   references. If you pass a ReferenceQueueinto a weak reference's
>   constructor, the reference object will be automatically inserted into
>   the reference queue when the object to which it pointed becomes
>   garbage. You can then, at some regular interval, process the
>   ReferenceQueue and perform whatever cleanup is needed for dead
>   references.

Sample code showing it:

```
    public static class A {
}

public  static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    A a = new A();

    ReferenceQueue<A> rq = new ReferenceQueue<A>();
    WeakReference<A> aref = new WeakReference<A>(a, rq);    
    a = null;

    //aref.get() should be a, aref.isEnqueued() should return false, rq.poll() should return null
    System.out.println( "0: " + aref + " : " + aref.get() + " : " + aref.isEnqueued() + "  " + rq.poll() ); 

    Thread.sleep(1000);

    System.out.println("Running GC.");
    Runtime.getRuntime().gc();  //let GC clear aref
    System.out.println("GC ran.");

    //aref.get() should be null, aref.isEnqueued() should return false, rq.poll() should return null
    System.out.println( "1: " + aref + " : " + aref.get() + " " + aref.isEnqueued() + "  " + rq.poll()  );   

    //give some time for GC to enqueue aref
    Thread.sleep(1000);

    //ref.get() should be null, aref.isEnqueued() should return true, rq.poll() should return aref
    System.out.println( "2: " + aref + " : " + aref.get() + " " + aref.isEnqueued() + "  " + rq.poll() );  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Does the Java GC clear a weak reference atomically with placing the weak reference on the ReferenceQueue assigned to that reference?

No. It is queued ['at the same time or some later time'](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ref/WeakReference.html). Nothing atomic about that specification.

> In other words, if a call to `WeakReference.get()` returns null, will the `WeakReference` be on the queue?

Not necessarily. Note that this isn't really 'in other words' at all: it isn't the same question.

Comment: I don't think I understand why these are not the same question (acknowledging that my second question would be more accurately phrased as, "will the WeakReference be guaranteed to be on the queue?").

Comment: Well, the answer to that rewording is 'no', and the answer to the original wording is 'not necessarily', so they're not the same question.